# facebook connect for ios question authentication application id and secret

Tags: iphone, authentication, ios, facebook

perhaps a stupid question, yet...
We're using the "new" ios facebook connect sdk (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) and a few questions come to mind.

In the old sdk, you would have to pass a "secret key" (known only to you) in order to obtain a session so that you could use the facebook api, this made sense.

With the new sdk, all you need to pass is "Application Id" and then the user logs in, then he is able to post any message and it will appear as if my application (the facebook application identified by the application id) posted it.

This makes little sense to us, if someone obtains our application id (not mentioned to be a secret anywhere), he/she will (without any problem) have the ability to post as if he was the owner of our facebook application.

Can someone explain this and how this is prevented using this new SDK?

a few more issues we're unclear about are:

1. in the facebook application
   settings, there is a choice between
   "Native application" and "HTML5 /
   mobile web" currently ours is set to
   HTML5/Mobile web (which is the
   default) what's the deal here?
   perhaps this correlates to the
   previous issue?
2. there are two more settings: "iOS Bundle ID" and
       "iTunes App Store ID" it is again
       unclear what these are used for. 
       Currently none of these 2 are set in
       our app and we're able to submit to
       user walls without a problem using
       the "application id" only in our
       iPhone app.

Any tips and hints appreciated!
thanx,
-tzurs

Comment: I know this is a million years old, but I have the same question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21532316/why-is-it-secure-for-the-facebook-sdk-to-authenticate-with-the-bundle-id-instead). Would you mind answering there or to this question if you found a satisfying answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

iOS Bundle ID is used to prevent that from happening. You specify the bundle id in your info.plst (e.g., com.your_company.your_app) so Facebook knows that your iPhone app is authorized to use your Facebook appication.

iTunes App Store ID is used to create a link from your Facebook application's page to your iPhone app on the app store.

Comment: I did not notice any "validation" of the plist bundle id and the authorization of posting, I might be missing something but i'm able to post from the iPhone app using ANY bundle id, no matter what is stated in the facebook application page. so I'm not sure this is the right answer or I'm still missing the full loop here.

Comment: It's intended purpose is to "secure the login experience on iOS" i.e. make sure the app is authorized. It appears that this is a known issue and they are developing a new method of security - http://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues#issue/188

Comment: @Tzur anything else you're missing?

Comment: If i have an existing fb connect website,  i'm not sure how can i interface the user logging in with fb on ios with my site?  Can't anyone send a valid access token to my site.  How would I know if the user successfully signed on fb via the the facebook login on iphone or just randomly got a valid access token?

Comment: This is totally stupid and doesnt make sense. Why on earth would anybody require my itunes Store ID JUST so they "create a link from your Facebook application's page to your iPhone app on the app store." Frankly, i cant help but think Facebook is just trying to get more control than they really need.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar: my id is:`326306604`. try going here: http://itunes.apple.com/app/id326306604. ID's are easy to find by anyone, it's no big secret. However, I have yet to see how Facebook uses this to give my users a download link. I'm still skeptical about the bundleID and what it's actual purpose is/will be used for.

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question. Can you answer "If someone obtains our application ID, he/she will have the ability to post as if he was the owner of our facebook application. Can someone explain this and how this is prevented using this new SDK?". Could you please elaborate on that?