# iOS - Facebook SDK integration/setup

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

Facebook SDK asks that developers provide their App ID as well as their iTunes ID.

Anybody feel this is incredibly ridiculous, not to mention ridiculously suspicious? Every doc/comment I've seen claims Facebook requires our iTunes ID so that they can "link" our app from iTunes, or something to this affect.

But i know for certain that this is not the case as there is a standard URL we can provide that lead users to the app, directly on iTunes/app-store.

The URL i commented on related to this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484677/facebook-connect-for-ios-question-authentication-application-id-and-secret/5024604#comment-6957319)

*** Update ***

OK. I don't think I'm doing this right. The App ID, which is provided by Facebook, this is the string that i provided in the Apple Store ID field. Which I'm pretty sure is WRONG. However, i am able to post to Facebook. What the hell is this field for?

*** Resolved ***

The apple store id is the App ID that you see from the app information page on apples developer site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a big misunderstanding. Facebook doesn't want or require your iTunes Id. It's an optional feature to register an url sheme for your application to provide a single sign login via the Facebook app on your iPhone.

> Bind your application to a URL scheme
>   corresponding to your Facebook
>   application ID. The URL scheme you
>   must bind to is of the format
>   "fb[appId]://", where [appId] is your
>   Facebook application ID. Without this,
>   your application won't be able to
>   handle authorization callbacks. Modify
>   your application's .plist file as
>   follows:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

Comment: It is a big misunderstanding because facebook has decided to use words that it clearly misleading. Shame on them. So then just to confirm... is the App ID the application Id, or is that a Url as well? Thanks!

Comment: Ok. I populated the Apple Store ID Url with the App Id format fb\appid\ mentioned in the FB SDK. Now im wondering what the API KEY and the APP SECRET strings are all about???

Comment: Ok. i dont think im doing this right. The App ID, which is provided by Facebook, this is the string that i provided in the Apple Store ID field. Which im pretty sure is WRONG. However, i am able to post to Facebook. What the hell is this field for???